# MapReduce Function with JSON Files and JSONParser

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

i have some problems during writing my mapreduce funtions.
I want to solve the following problem:

I have a JSON file with 1mio JSONObject like this:

```
 {"_id":3951,"title":"Two Family House (2000)","genres":["Drama"],"ratings":[{"userId":173,"rating":5},{"userId":195,"rating":5},{"userId":411,"rating":4},{"userId":593,"rating":2},{"userId":629,"rating":3},{"userId":830,"rating":3},{"userId":838,"rating":5},{"userId":850,"rating":4},{"userId":856,"rating":4},{"userId":862,"rating":5},{"userId":889,"rating":1},{"userId":928,"rating":5},{"userId":986,"rating":4},{"userId":1001,"rating":5},{"userId":1069,"rating":3},{"userId":1168,"rating":3},{"userId":1173,"rating":2},{"userId":1242,"rating":3},{"userId":1266,"rating":5},{"userId":1331,"rating":5},{"userId":1417,"rating":5},{"userId":1470,"rating":4},{"userId":1474,"rating":5},{"userId":1615,"rating":3},{"userId":1625,"rating":4},{"userId":1733,"rating":4},{"userId":1799,"rating":4},{"userId":1865,"rating":5},{"userId":1877,"rating":5},{"userId":1897,"rating":5},{"userId":1946,"rating":4},{"userId":2031,"rating":4},{"userId":2129,"rating":2},{"userId":2353,"rating":4},{"userId":2986,"rating":4},{"userId":3940,"rating":4},{"userId":3985,"rating":3},{"userId":4025,"rating":5},{"userId":4727,"rating":3},{"userId":5333,"rating":3}]}
```

and more....

One JSON Object is a Movie, which contains a array ratings. I want to count all ratings in the JSON File.

I created a Maven Proct in IntelliJ with the dependencys for Hadoop and JSON Parser. My MapReduce Class is this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RatingCounter {

public static class RatingMapper extends Mapper<JSONObject, Text, Text, Text>{

    private Text id = new Text();
    private Text ratingAnzahl = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(value.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String movieId = (String) jsonObject.get("_id");

            int count = 0;
            // loop array
            JSONArray ratings = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("ratings");
            Iterator<String> iterator = ratings.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                count++;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public static class RatingReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Text resultValue = new Text();

        int allRatings = 0;

        while (values.hasNext()){
            allRatings += Integer.parseInt(values.toString());

        }
        resultValue.set(""+allRatings);
        context.write(key, resultValue);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "ratings count");
    job.setJarByClass(RatingCounter.class);
    job.setMapperClass(RatingMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(RatingReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

I have no idea, how I can write the functions in Mapper and Reducer. Can someone help me pls?

Comment: I see that you haven't passed key value pairs from your mapper class to the reducer. I think thats your problem

Comment: Any reason not to use Spark or Hive?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes to your mapper and reducer.

First, for your mapper, you are not writing the output anywhere and your syntax while extending the `Mapper` class is also wrong(arguably). The first input to any mapper is a `LongWritable` (or `Object` type) offset of line. You can notice the changes below

```
public static class RatingMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, ParseException{
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = parser.parse(value.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String movieId = (String) jsonObject.get("_id");

        JSONArray ratings = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("ratings");

        context.write(new Text(movieId), new IntWritable(ratings.size()) );
    }
}
```

Notice here, the output of map is written using `context.write`

Now, coming onto your `Reducer` some things will change because of the changes I made in the mapper. Also, since your **Number of Ratings** will always be an integer, you don't need to convert it to `Text`, use `parseInt` and then convert to `Text` again.

```
public static class RatingReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int allRatings = 0;

        while (values.hasNext()){
            allRatings += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(resultValue));
    }
}
```